# How to insert crrectly opcache_compile_file inside application?

Tags: php, opcache

1/ I have not knowledge in cache but I would know if it's correct to write this code with `opcache_compile_file`;

2/ How to check if `opcache` exits or not ?

```
  $filename = 'toto.php;

  if (is_file($filename)) {
    ob_start();
    opcache_compile_file($filename);
    $new_prods_content .= ob_get_clean();
  } else {
    echo CLICSHOPPING::getDef('template_does_not_exist') . '<br /> ' . $filename;
    exit;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first line is missing `'`. It should read:

```php
$filename = 'toto.php';
```

Next, `opcache_compile_file()` itself only compiles and caches a PHP script, but does not execute it. See [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.opcache-compile-file.php). If you need to actually execute the script, you have to include it (e.g. using [`include`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)/[`include_once`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php) or [`require`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.require.php)/[`require_once`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php)).

To check if opcache is loaded and enabled, you can do something like this:

```php
if (
    function_exists('opcache_get_status') &&
    ($opcache_status = opcache_get_status()) &&
    $opcache_status['opcache_enabled']
) {
    // opcache is enabled
}
```

Finally, if opcache is loaded, it is likely already enabled for all your web scripts, so you don't need to manually compile scripts at all. You can use [opcache-gui](https://github.com/amnuts/opcache-gui) to get some insights on what's going on under the hood in your opcache.